# python 3.5 beginner : Elif giving "invalid syntax" but I can't see an indentation error

Tags: python, python-3.5

I'm sorry; it seems that this error is pretty common, yet I can't see how I may have had done an indentation error, there's no tabs, only spaces..

```
def impots(revenus):
 imp=0
 if revenus < 9690:
  return(imp)
 elif revenus < 26764:
  return ((0.14*(revenus-9690))
 elif revenus < 71754:
  return (0.30*(revenus-26764)+2390,36)
 else :
  return (°)
```

could you help me ? Thanks and sorry again

Comment: After correction, there is another problem in your code : `return (°)` will raise a syntax error. BTW, parenthesis after `return` is useless.

Comment: Line 6, there is 3 opening parenthesis but only 2 closing ones

Comment: the return wasn't what I intended to really return, but thanks !
And thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing a ")" after revenus-9690.

```
 def impots(revenus):
 imp=0
 if revenus < 9690:
  return(imp)
 elif revenus < 26764:
  return ((0.14*(revenus-9690)))
 elif revenus < 71754:
  return (0.30*(revenus-26764)+2390,36)
 else :
  return (°)
```

Comment: god thanks a lot I feel terribly stupid

Comment: @Dekharen No problem I do it a lot. A best answer would be appreciated :)